# Makefile to Compile OpenCV Code in C++ on Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: opencv, compilation, makefile, cmake

I am learning OpenCV using [Learning OpenCV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134) book.

One problem I am facing while compiling the code is that I have to write a long command to compile and get the executable.

This is the command I am using

```
g++ `pkg-config –cflags opencv` file_name.cpp -o output_file `pkg-config –libs opencv`
```

I am no **Make** expert but I think I can eliminate writing that long command using **make**.
Before that I should explain my work flow. I have created a directory called opencv in my home directory (`~/opencv/`). I am reading the book section by section and coding the examples or exercises into new cpp source code files in that directory. *So I don't know the names of the files before hand.*

Now what I want make to do is,

Suppose I have coded a new file named `facedetect.cpp` in my `opencv` directory, and if I call make like this

```
make facedetect
```

then I want make to execute the following command for me

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` facedetect.cpp -o facedetect `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

so that whenever I make a new file named abc.cpp, I will execute `make abc`
so that I can run

```
$ ./abc
```

at my command line to test my abc.cpp

Please give that make file so that I can save the frustration of typing that long command each time.

PS: I have Googled for help on this and found [this](http://thebitbangtheory.wordpress.com/2011/10/24/how-to-use-cmake-with-opencv/) on using ***CMake*** but I could not understand what that does. Kindly also explain how can I use ***CMake*** for the same task.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can create a file called `Makefile` in you working directory like this:

```
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs opencv`

% : %.cpp
        g++ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@ $<
```

then you can use this file for all your single-file programms. Just call `make` with the basename of the file you want to compile. For `facedetect.cpp` that would be

```
make facedetect
```

Here some more details:

The general format of a makefile is like this:

```
target : dependecy1 dependenc2 ...
    command that generates the target
```

So for your example you could write:

```
facedetect : facedetect.cpp
    g++  $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o facedetect facedetect.cpp
```

For each new example you can now create a new target. But you can also make it more general:

```
% : %.cpp
    g++  $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@ $<
```

Here `%` matches any nonempty substring. The automatic variables `$@` and `$<` substitute the names of the target file and the source file.
For more information you can consult the [make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/).

Comment: It looks like only `g++ $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LIBS)` will work. But I think that is a opencv thing. Thanks for the Makefile. Can u explain what does that mean or give any good resource to learn about Make

Comment: Good resources about make: [make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html). It's not as scary and hard to understand as it looks.

Comment: Thanks Siva Prasad Varma, it was indeed the **order** of the arguments. `$(LIBS)` **must go at the end of the compilation command**, or OpenCV examples themselves will not compile!

Comment: You can just use `LDLIBS = \`pkg-config --libs opencv\`` without explicitly writing the build command.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/33530363/order-in-makefile also about the order.

Answer (score 6):

GNU Make is pretty smart and the Makefile you need for this doesn't need to be as verbose as in the other answers given so far. Here is a simple Makefile which you can use to compile the OpenCV examples:

```
CPPFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags opencv)
LDLIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs opencv)
```

That's it. The Makefile can be this short thanks to Make's [implicit rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules).

Then run `make` as usual:

```
make facedetect
```

This assumes there is a `facedetect.c` or `facedetect.cpp` in the same directory.

I recommend the following (free!) book if you want to learn Make: http://oreilly.com/catalog/make3/book/index.csp

Comment: today, you can simply install cmake(if not already installed => sudo apt-get install cmake); open a terminal; navigate to opencv folder; cmake .; make; note the "."(dot) after cmake, now, wait for everything to be built

Comment: @ComputerSaysNo: I think you misunderstood the question. He's not trying to compile OpenCV, but source files that he wrote himself from exercises in a book (which use the OpenCV libraries).

Comment: ahhh, yes, misunderstood badly, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named `makefile` in your working directory that contains the following:

```
CFLAGS = $SHELL(pkg-config --cflags opencv)
LIBS = $SHELL(pkg-config --libs opencv)

facedetect : facedetect.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@ $<
```

Then when you want to compile you just type:

```
$ make
```

(To answer your *PS* - note that `CMake` is very different from `make` - for now you should probaby just use `make`.)